# How to run python scripts and packages on Visual Studio

Tags: ironpython

I have a python program to control LIFX smart bulb.I require the python code to run on Visual Studio through Iron Python. The python program is present on GitHub:

https://github.com/mclarkk/lifxlan

The program has two directories:

1. examples: It contains python scripts to control the Lifx bulb lightning.
2. lifxlan: This is a package which is used by python scripts.

So far, I was able to download Iron Python package present in visual studio. I can run a simple python print script, like print ("hello world"). These are the two problems I have:

1. when I run breathe_all.py file (present in examples directory), I get the error:

   No module named copy

I don't know what it means by no module named copy. I thought this feature was present in IronPy.

2. How do I make sure that lifxlan package is supported by IronPy. So far, I just copy and paste the whole python program into visual studio project folder. I don't know if this is the proper way.

Thank you for your help and support,

python script: breathe_all

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
import sys
from copy import copy
from time import sleep, time

from lifxlan import LifxLAN


def main():
    num_lights = None
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("\nDiscovery will go much faster if you provide the number of lights on your LAN:")
    print("  python {} <number of lights on LAN>\n".format(sys.argv[0]))
else:
    num_lights = int(sys.argv[1])

# instantiate LifxLAN client, num_lights may be None (unknown).
# In fact, you don't need to provide LifxLAN with the number of bulbs at all.
# lifx = LifxLAN() works just as well. Knowing the number of bulbs in advance
# simply makes initial bulb discovery faster.
lifx = LifxLAN(num_lights) #problem may occur in loading LifxLAN

# test power control
print("Discovering lights...")
original_powers = lifx.get_power_all_lights()
original_colors = lifx.get_color_all_lights()

half_period_ms = 2500
duration_mins = 20
duration_secs = duration_mins*60
print("Breathing...")
try:
    start_time = time()
    while True:
        for bulb in original_colors:
            color = original_colors[bulb]
            dim = list(copy(color))
            dim[2] = 1900
            bulb.set_color(dim, half_period_ms, rapid=True)
        sleep(half_period_ms/1000.0)
        for bulb in original_colors:
            color = original_colors[bulb]
            bulb.set_color(color, half_period_ms, rapid=True)
        sleep(half_period_ms/1000.0)
        if time() - start_time > duration_secs:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Restoring original color to all lights...")
    for light in original_colors:
        color = original_colors[light]
        light.set_color(color)

    print("Restoring original power to all lights...")
    for light in original_powers:
        power = original_powers[light]
        light.set_power(power)

if __name__=="__main__":
     main()
```

visual Studio:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace Test01
{
    class Program
     {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //ipy is the python interpreter
            var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
        dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("C:\\Users\\..\\source\\repos\\Test01\\Test01\\example\\breathe_all.py");
            test.main();

    }
}
```

}

Error:

Exception thrown:

```
'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in 
 Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
 An unhandled exception of type 
 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' occurred in 
 Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
 No module named copy
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I do have python installed on visual studio.

Comment: How do I fix the error: no module named copy.